# How can I get the entity inside an event listener of a form type?

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms

I want to get the value of the attribute `id` of an entity, so how can I get the entity inside an event listener of a form type?

I tried this below, but `$event->getData()` is outputting the Type Form class itself. I need the entity to write `$entity->getId()`.

```
$builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::POST_SET_DATA, function (FormEvent $event) {
  $data = $event->getData();
```

Comment: a bit hackish, but you can put the id in a hidden field (waiting to find a better answer)

Comment: @allan.simon thanks, thats sound useful, but I don't know exactly how to retrieve the `id` value inside the event listener..

Comment: You probably want to use PRE_SET_DATA.  I know getData will give you the entity. http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/form/form_events.html#pre-populating-the-form-formevents-pre-set-data-and-formevents-post-set-data Not sure of the use case for POST_SET.

Comment: Both pre_set_data and post_set_data should give you the model data (that is, your entity, if it's the root form). It strange that you get the form type class (`getData` should never return the form type class).